# How to determine if SharePoint is online when using MS-Access and VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, sharepoint-online

I am using Office 365 with MS-Access that is tied to a SharePoint list.  I have some VBA code that runs with the user clicks on a command button.  Part of the code appends data to a table.  Unfortunately, one user kept trying to use the command button not realizing that the connection to SharePoint, (for some reason), was lost.  Everytime she clicked on the command button it appended the same data.  I need some vba code that checks if SharePoint is online for MS-Access.  If it is, it runs the query.  If it isn't the coded exits along with a message.  It's finding out if SharePoint is online for MS-Access that I need help on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are in off-line mode, and you have the cache turned on, then that user should  be able to freely add records. The PK will start at -1, then -2 and so on.

You could check for a internet connection, but if they are flipped into off line mode, then Access will often remain in off line mode.

So, you could have a dummy table, and add a record - if  the PK is < 0 then you are off line (and delete that dummy record). I am not aware there is some command that will tell you that you are in fact on-line. I suppose you could also "ping" the server with a shell() command, but as I stated, you can actually be off line with a valid connection, so to be really sure the negative PK trick would tell you for sure if Access "thinks" and is "behaving" as if it is in off line mode.

It is not clear why the button fails, but if you have the check box "use SharePoint 2010 or later cache) selected, then users should be free to edit, view and add records. when you re-connect, then access will sync all the changes and updates (bi-directional sync).

Answer (score 0):

Albert.  Thank you, your suggestion was helpful.  I did some testing by disconnecting my computer from the Internet and then running the code attached to the command button.  Like you said, in the SharePoint table, (not a temporary table), all of the records imported have a PK <0, i.e.-1, -2, -3, etc.  I wrote a simple DCount query looking for PK's less than zero.  What was interesting is that the query could not count any PK less than zero, only PK's >0.  My workabout in the criteria was to place, Like ("-*") and that worked.  Wierd that the PK is an autonumber field, a number, but less than zero didn't work.  With the DCount criteria I created a MsgBox that explained what was going on and how to get SharePoint back on line if there Internet connection was still up.  AND, don't import the same spreadsheet again, (which was part of the code.  So, thank you.